# Looking for proportions on bulk cold brew preparation (2.5 or 5 gal batches)

Tags: cold-brew

I'm preparing to serve Cold Brew coffee at a local renaissance festival (billed as "alchemy & potions").  I've looked into various bulk / semi-commercial systems, most of which are in the 5 gallon container range.  I'll have access to a large industrial sink, large refrigerators, etc. So far, so good.

The one thing I cannot find is a reliable ratio of coffee grounds to water, that also specifies if the result will be able to be served straight, or it will be a concentrate that will need to be diluted.  I've seen ratios by volume of 1 cup Grounds to 4 cups water, 1 to 8, and also 1 pound per Gallon.  (I did the 1:4 at home in a 1-gallon jar and it was VERY strong - I'm guessing that was the Concentrate ratio...)

The general plan is to set up the container in the evening (around 8 or 9 PM), set it in the refrigerator overnight, and around 9:00 AM drain it into serving containers, so it has 12 hours to steep.  I can do longer if that works better, but I imagine that will be impacted by the amount of coffee grounds I am using as well.

Can anyone offer guidance on the best volume / weight of grounds to use for a 5 gallon container (using a coffee sock or other filter), how long to let that volume brew, and if the result will be drinkable or needs to be diluted?  I can't get a clear answer that covers all three variables at once.

Thank you!